# How to run script if gmail subject contains " "

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, gmail-api, google-sheets-api

I have a script that imports CSV gmail attachments to google sheets, it runs every minute. I have another script that copies data to another sheet, I'd like to include the copy script to run after the import CSV script `IF` the email Subject line contains "END OF DAY SALES DETAILS".  This happens once per day, throughout the day the Subject line contains "SALES DETAILS".

Would need a small delay after importing CSV to ensure everything was fully processed, will achieve with `Utilities.sleep()` If Subject line contains the expected string.

Import CSV script:

```
function importCSVFromGmail() { 
  //gets first(latest) message with set label
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('South Loop Sales').getThreads(0,1);     
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

  // Is the attachment a CSV file
  attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {                            
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Silverware-Sales");
    //parses content of csv to array
    var dataString = attachment.getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(dataString);
    // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
    sh.clearContents().clearFormats();                                         
    //pastes array to sheet
    var lastRowValue = sh.getLastRow();
    for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
       sh.getRange(i+lastRowValue+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    } 
    if( message.getSubject() != 'END OF DAY SALES DETAILS' ) {
    logTodaysSales()
}
  }

  //marks the Gmail message as read, unstars it and deletes it using Gmail API (Filter sets a star)
  message.markRead();
  message.unstar();
  Gmail.Users.Messages.remove("me", message.getId()); // Added

}

//The code formats the code so it can be entered into the Google Script

function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ){ 
  // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
  // then default to comma.
  strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

  // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
  var objPattern = new RegExp(
    (
      // Delimiters.
      "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +


      // Quoted fields.
      "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +


      // Standard fields.
      "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
    ),
    "gi"
  );


  // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
  // a default empty first row.
  var arrData = [[]];

  // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
  // matching groups.
  var arrMatches = null;

  // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
  // until we can no longer find a match.
  while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

    // Get the delimiter that was found.
    var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

    // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
    // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
    // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
    // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
    if (
      strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
      (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
    ){

      // Since we have reached a new row of data,
      // add an empty row to our data array.
      arrData.push( [] );

    }

    // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
    // let's check to see which kind of value we
    // captured (quoted or unquoted).
    if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

      // We found a quoted value. When we capture
      // this value, unescape any double quotes.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
        new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
        "\""
      );

    } else {

      // We found a non-quoted value.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

    }

    // Now that we have our value string, let's add
    // it to the data array.
    arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
  }

  // Return the parsed data.
  return( arrData );
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("South Loop Report");
  label.deleteLabel();
}
```

Copy data script:

```
function logTodaysSales() {
  var todaysSales = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Silverware-Log!SilverwareImport');
  var logSheet = todaysSales.getSheet();
  logSheet.appendRow(
    todaysSales.getValues()
    .reduce(function(a, b) { return a.concat(b); }) // flatten the 2D array to 1D
  );
}
```

Comment: To add a delay, look up the `Utilities.sleep()` function in the apps script reference documentation.

Comment: That will work perfectly for the delay between the 2 scripts, thank you.  I'm also looking for a way to execute the script if the Subject line contains "END OF DAY SALES DETAILS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the message variable you have at the beginning of the importCSVFromGmail function, you can get the message subject with getSubject [1] function and use the result in an If condition:

```
if( message.getSubject() == 'END OF DAY SALES DETAILS' ) {
    //Do what you need
}
```

If you want to filter the emails that include the string 'END OF DAY SALES DETAILS' in their subject and not only the exact matches (Like the one above), use indexOf()[2] function in the `if` condition:

```
message.getSubject().indexOf('END OF DAY SALES DETAILS') !== -1
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getSubject()

[2] https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be pulling all of them and executing the script each time as opposed to ones that only contain “END OF DAY SALES”. Likely due to the subject line being similar.

Comment: Please edit the question with the new code you're using. May be the subject is not in capital letters? It must be an exact match.

Comment: Updated question with current script.
Subject line of unwanted executions reads: 

"SilverWare Insight - South Loop (Michigan Ave) - SALES DETAILS"

Case sensitive.

Comment: perhaps it would be easier to pull from an additional label?

Filing End Of Day emails under "South Loop EOD"

Comment: So you should use "SilverWare Insight - South Loop (Michigan Ave) - SALES DETAILS" instead of 'END OF DAY SALES DETAILS'. Yes, that's a most optimized option.

Comment: I want it to execute the copy function only if the subject includes END OF DAY SALES DETAILS, not just SALES DETAILS.

Currently it's executing that function for all emails.

Comment: Oh sorry I got confused, I edited the answer to that end.

Comment: should be 

```message.getSubject().includes('END OF DAY SALES DETAILS') == true```

Right?

Comment: Yeah, mistaken again haha, I just fixed it.

Comment: While it's now not executing the copy script on the unwanted emails, it seems the delete email portion at the bottom has stopped working.

```
  //marks the Gmail message as read, unstars it and deletes it using Gmail API (Filter sets a star)
  message.markRead();
  message.unstar();
  Gmail.Users.Messages.remove("me", message.getId()); // Added

}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's not executing the delete clause due to this error?

```
TypeError: Cannot find function includes in object SilverWare Insight - South Loop (Michigan Ave) - SALES DETAILS. (line 22, file "sales import")
```

Comment: Yeah, includes() is not supported by Apps Script yet (next version will). I edited the question with the indexOf() as you used it.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your script a little bit to accept a message as an input and create a new function to check on your email subjects.

```
function checkSALES() {
var thread = GmailApp.search('subject:"SALES DETAILS"', 0, 1);
var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
importCSVFromGmail(message)
}

function checkEndOfDay() {
var thread = GmailApp.search('subject:"SALES DETAILS"', 0, 1);
var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
importCSVFromGmail(message)
}


function importCSVFromGmail(message) { 
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
...
```

Then I would just set the triggers on each function at the frequency you want them to run at.